# Android removing an item from a gridview

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application that contains a gridview. I'm filling this grid with a customized adapter containing an image and a text.

```
adapter = new CustomGrid(this, titlearray, imageId);
         grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
           grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I click on any item, a dialog opens containing a button, what I want is when I click on this button the item will be removed. I checked many solutions, they said I should change the adapter or use a new one.

I tried the following code, I'm putting the data in new arrays and loading them in the adapter then using them in the grid :

```
                    String[] ntarray=new String[wcount];    
                    Drawable[] ndarray=new Drawable[wcount];





                if(position==0)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<wcount;i++)
                    {
                        ntarray[i]=titlearray[i+1];
                        ndarray[i]=imageId[i+1];
                    }
                }


                if(position==wcount-1)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<wcount-1;i++)
                    {
                        ntarray[i]=titlearray[i];
                        ndarray[i]=imageId[i];
                    }
                }


                 adapter = new CustomGrid(Wishlist.this, ntarray, ndarray);
                   grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   dialog.hide();
```

I'm using a custom grid adapter :

```
package com.erc.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Drawable[] Imageid;
      public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,Drawable[] imageId ) {
          mContext = c;
          this.Imageid = imageId;
          this.web = web;
      }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return web.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View grid;
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            Button textView = (Button) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(web[position]);
           // textView.setShadowLayer(2, 1, 1, Color.BLACK);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(Imageid[position]);
          } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
          }
      return grid;
    }
}
```

Is there any function or any method that can help me removing this item without creating a new adapter, if yes how can I add it in my customgrid class ?

Comment: Why don't you just add a remove() function to your listadapter and have that remote() from your list? Next call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on the existing adapter and it should update/refresh

Comment: You can create a method inside your custom adapter, that remove the item from *ntarray* and *ndarray* then you call *notifyDataSetChanged();* to update your gridview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make those changes:

```
    ArrayList<String> ntarray= new ArrayList<String>();    
    ArrayList<Drawable> ndarray= new ArrayList<Drawable>();

    if(position==0){
      for(int i=0;i<wcount;i++){
          ntarray.set(i, titlearray[i+1]);
          ndarray.set(i, imageId[i+1]);
      }
    }

   if(position==wcount-1){
      for(int i=0;i<wcount-1;i++){
         ntarray.set(i, titlearray[i]);
         ndarray.set(i, imageId[i]);
      }
   }

   adapter = new CustomGrid(Wishlist.this, ntarray, ndarray);
   grid.setAdapter(adapter);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   dialog.hide();
```

and in your adapter:

```
    public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private final ArrayList<String> web;
        private final ArrayList<Drawable> Imageid;

        public CustomGrid(Context c, ArrayList<String> web, ArrayList<Drawable> imageId ) {
              mContext = c;
              this.Imageid = imageId;
              this.web = web;
          }

        public void removeItem(int position){
             web.remove(position);
             Imageid.remove(position);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    ....
    }
```

and when you want to remove an item in the gridview, just call: `adapter.removeItem(TheItemPosition);`

**Update**

You can add this method in your adapter to clear all items:

```
public void clearData(){
      web.clear();
      Imageid.clear();
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up @Rami Thank you :D

Comment: one more question, how can I clear all the items from the adapter ?